# Spring Security OAuth2 AuthorizationServer

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, microservices

I'm playing around with spring-security-oauth2. I try to build some microservices with an authentication backend.

I set up an simple spring boot project with the following dependencies

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and one Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("clientDetailsServiceBean")
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceBean")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
    public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        @Bean(name = "authenticationManagerBean")
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().userDetailsService(userDetailsService).formLogin().and().httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore());
        }

        @Bean
        public ApprovalStore approvalStore() throws Exception {
            TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
            store.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            return store;
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            security.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
            security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }

    }
```

My Implementation of Client- and UserDetailsService are very simple and always returns an object

```
@Service("clientDetailsServiceBean")
public class ClientDetailsServiceBean implements ClientDetailsService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientDetailsServiceBean.class);

    @Override
    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
        LOGGER.info("Load client {}", clientId); 
        BaseClientDetails details = new BaseClientDetails();
        details.setClientId(clientId);
        details.setAuthorizedGrantTypes(Arrays.asList("password", "refresh_token", "client_credentials"));
        details.setScope(Arrays.asList("trust"));
        details.setAutoApproveScopes(Arrays.asList("trust"));
        details.setAuthorities(Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("client_role2")));
        details.setResourceIds(Arrays.asList("clients"));
        details.setClientSecret("secret");

        return details;
    }

}
@Service("userDetailsServiceBean")
public class UserDetailsServiceBean implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsServiceBean.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        LOGGER.info("Load user {}", username);
        return new User(username, "password", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")) );
    }
}
```

But, when i try to receive an accessToken via

```
curl http://localhost:8081/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials -d client_id=web_client -d client_secret=secret
```

i receive an error "Full authentication is required to access this resource" and when i try

```
curl http://localhost:8081/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials -d client_id=web_client -d client_secret=secret --user web_client:secret
```

i receive an error "Bad credentials". From my point of view both should work, but it seems like my configuration is missing.

There are other things with OAuth that unclear to me:
I try to build an spring-mvc application with spring-security and a custom login form. It's possible to handle token request and refresh cycles by spring security without redirect to the authentication app?

In case of event driven application, it's possible to ensure the token is valid? In case of failure, the user clicks on button and an event is written but the processing of this will be hours later. How can i process the event with the user credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner `@Configuration` classes need to be static. I'm surprised the app starts at all, and probably the whole of your `SecurityConfiguration` is actually not being used.

> It's possible to handle token request and refresh cycles by spring security without redirect to the authentication app?

Naturally. Did you read about the password and refresh_token grants in the spec? But in a web UI you are strongly advised to use the auth code grant (with the redirects), so that the user only enters his credentials in a trusted place.

> the user clicks on button and an event is written but the processing of this will be hours later. How can i process the event with the user credentials?

Refresh tokens might be the best approach. The event obviously needs to be secure since it will have to contain the refresh token.

Comment: Thank you, with your help I found my fail. 
We have multiple Web UI products and the microservice infrastructure should be hidden for our customers. Is there already some implementation for this in spring-security or spring-security-oauth2 or i have to implement AuthenticationProvider and Filter for this case?

Comment: I really don't know. You'd have to explain what "hidden" means and stackoverflow probably isn't the right place. There's a gitter.im room for spring-security-oauth if you want to chat.